# How to play video url without browser in window phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I want to play video with url in window phone :

```
 string urlVideo = "http://hcm.m.24h.com.vn/upload_mobile/2-2014/videoclip_hd/2014-05-15/1400104421-Sevilla_VS_Benfica_Cao_003.mp4";
 WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
 webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri(urlVideo , UriKind.Absolute);
 webBrowserTask.Show();
```

My problem is : When I open video,it will be open browser and then play video.But I wanna play video direct and don't open browser.

Comment: Do you want to play the video in your app, or do you want it to use the phone video player (the one that opens after the browser opens up)?

Comment: I want to use the phone video player

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way to really do this then is to download the entire video to your storage and use the `MediaPlayerLauncher` to play the video.

Kind'a sucks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try  [using `MediaPlayerLauncher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394004%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Don't forget use `UriKind.Absolute` because you're playing video from internet, for example :

```
string urlVideo = "http://hcm.m.24h.com.vn/upload_mobile/2-2014/videoclip_hd/2014-05-15/1400104421-Sevilla_VS_Benfica_Cao_003.mp4";
MediaPlayerLauncher mediaPlayerLauncher = new MediaPlayerLauncher();
mediaPlayerLauncher.Media = new Uri(urlVideo, UriKind.Absolute);
mediaPlayerLauncher.Show();
```